# I want to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 PC, but which of 4 partitions do I override?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

My PC came with the maximum of 4 partitions by default. How do I find out which partition contains Windows 7? I don't want to erase Windows; I want to dual boot Ubuntu on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Start - type in "computer management" and select "disk management" or just type in "disk management"
This will tell you what resides on which partition of each disk drive